# How to change audio src by click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change dynamically audio src using jquery?

```
  <audio id="audio" controls="" >
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>

<ul id="playlist">
  <?php if($lists) { foreach ($lists as $list) { ?>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="music/<?php  echo $list;  ?>.mp3">
         <?php  echo $list;  ?> </a>
    </li>   
  <?php }}?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to bind click event handler to `a` (or delegate events to parent `#playlist`) and assign new src to `#audio source`:

```
$('#playlist').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#audio source').attr('src', src);
});
```

Important: remember to prevent default behavior of `HTMLAnchorElement` on click which is page reload.

Answer (score 2):

You can give an id attribute to src of the source you want to change as,

```
<source src="" type="audio/mpeg" id="mySrc"/>
```

Now through jQuery,

```
$("#mySrc").attr("src","Your-Value");
```

Suppose you want to change the src value when a button is clicked, you can write,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#mySrc").attr("src","Your-Value");
    });
});
```

[**Here is a  demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/j2scwpxz/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery `.attr()` tag, check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5v0cd38n/).

More information about this tag [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
  $("#audio").attr("src", "new src here");
```

Comment: No problemo, my pleasure :)